# Barcode scanner and touch keyboard in Android

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen, barcode

If I connect the barcode scanner via blue-tooth with my Android tablet, the soft keyboard will be switched off and I can not visible the keyboard any longer. I have to disconnect the barcode reader first. Is there a way to use both (barcode scanner and touch keyboard)in the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your bar code is being recognized as Physical Keyboard. Hence the soft virtual keyboard on your android is been disabled..

Option 1: Try manually checking the keyboard setting after you connect the bar code reader.
Go to Settings -> Language & Input -> and check if the keyboard options are disabled and if so, try enabling them.

Option 2: Go to Settings -> Language & Input -> Keyboard ( & input methods) -> and check for "USE PHYSICAL KEYBOARD" and put it to "off".

If the above doesn't work, can you send the Phone model and Bar Code Model.

Comment: Yes, it was helpful, but I noticed it's doesn't work with any keyboard software. In my case I had to use a japanese keyboard and only the Google one works as well.

Comment: I'm not sure if your device supports "Android L Keyboard". You can give a try. Search in google play for "android L keyboard"..