# Use Virtual and Physical Keyboard at same time

Tags: keyboard, external-keyboard, android-versions

Previously I've read this article: [Article](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/73110/barcode-scanner-and-touch-keyboard-in-android), but it did not help.

I have an android device Samsung Galaxy V (Duos) - KitKat 4.4.2. I use this device to process the input using the Barcode Scanner.
I understand the barcode scanner will be detected as a physical keyboard, and I also understand that when these devices are connected, then I can not use the Virtual Keyboard.

The question is, how do I be able to use virtual keyboard while physical keyboard connected?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know adding a keyboard will edit a setting. The keyboard doesnt show up instantly when you put your cursor into an input field, but when you press more often (at least at my s3) the regular keyboard pops up on my screen.
I hope this works for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "adding a keyboard will edit a setting"?

Comment: Still I could not use my virtual keyboard even though I touch input box repeatedly. 
How many times have you touch input box until appears a virtual keyboard?
Is your physical keyboard are still connected and can be used both?